# React crop image library that also can move or resize image

Tags: css, image, reactjs, crop

I am looking for a image library with React. What I want to do is that there is a fixed editor and I can move and resize the image behind the editor and if the image in the editor is what I want, then I get fixed image's baseUrl. I found a few libraries, but those are only giving cropped function not moving or resizing image. I hope to find out cropped image library plus that can move or resize image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-avatar-editor

Sounds like what you're describing, including the base64 export.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of packages around, the most recommended one is react-avatar-image-cropper.

Have a look at it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-avatar-image-cropper